# How can I extract and get the values from this response in C#

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var process = new com.globalpay.certapia.GlobalPayments();
        var response = process.ProcessCreditCard("xxxxxx", "xxxxxx", "Sale",
            textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, "", "", textBox3.Text, "",
            "", "", "", "", "");

        MessageBox.Show("RespMSG: " + response.RespMSG
            + "\nMessage: " + response.Message
            + "\nAuthCode: " + response.AuthCode
            + "\nPNRef: " + response.PNRef
            + "\nHostCode: " + response.HostCode
            + "\nCVResultTXT: " + response.GetCVResultTXT
            + "\nCommercialCard: " + response.GetCommercialCard
            + "\nExtData: " + response.ExtData);
    }
```

The output goes like this:

[image]

In the part of ExtData I got confused I do not know how can I extract those values like get the value of CardType, BatchNum, MID, TransID.

How can I possibly extract those values?

Any advice or suggestion how can I achieve this will be a big help. Thanks!

base on the doc of api:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="GlobalPayments">
<Result>0</Result>
<RespMSG>Approved</RespMSG>
<Message>AP</Message>
<AuthCode>000014</AuthCode>
<PNRef>564286</PNRef>
<HostCode>0032</HostCode>
<GetCVResultTXT>Service Not Requested</GetCVResultTXT>
<GetCommercialCard>False</GetCommercialCard>
<ExtData>InvNum=1234567900,CardType=MasterCard,BatchNum=0011<BatchNum>0011
</BatchNum><ReceiptData><MID>4910354</MID><Trans_Id>MCC1421250315
</Trans_Id></ReceiptData></ExtData>
</Response>
```

Comment: Sorry what sort of response is that? Doesn't look http...

Comment: If ExtData always has the same format, you could extract the XML portion and then use LINQ-to-XML to extract BatchNum, MID and TransID, and use a simple String.Split to get CardType.

Comment: This looks like original response was parsed incorrectly. Can you please show us contents of ProcessCreditCard? Most preferably how you turn the (presumably) text response into a response type.

Comment: Info on the ParseCreditCard method:  [GlobalPayments Web Service](https://certapia.globalpay.com/GlobalPay/transact.asmx?op=ProcessCreditCard)

Comment: Can you pleast post RAW, non-parsed resposne from this service?

Comment: Updated my question sirs

Comment: What is it with Card Processors and their inability to use XML properly?  Nesting XML elements in an element that also contains text?  I thought the one I had to deal with was a pain...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LINQ would be the easiest way, assuming the response is a string or something you can turn into a string:

```
// XDocument.Parse will load a string into the XDocument object.
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(response);
// XNamespace is required in order to parse the document.
XNamespace ns = "GlobalPayments";

var resp = (from x in xDoc.Descendants(ns + "ExtData")
            select new
            {
                ExtData = x.Value,
                BatchNum = x.Element(ns + "BatchNum").Value,
                MID = x.Element(ns + "MID").Value,
                TransID = x.Element(ns + "TransID").Value
            }).SingleOrDefault();
```

You would then have an anonymous type (`resp`) with the following propertries:

```
resp.ExtData = "InvNum=1234567900,CardType=MasterCard,BatchNum=0011"
resp.BatchNum = "0011"
resp.MID = "4910354"
resp.TransID = "MCC1421250315"
```

You could then use normal String.Split operations on ExtData to get the data from that string you need.

Not the prettiest solution, but sometimes you have to brute force methods.  Adopt and modify to suit your needs/tastes.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be case of incorrectly formatted response. This is quite common with these kind of webservices. Don't expect it to get better any time soon.

You simply need to brute-force the parsing and hope they don't change it or it is changed based on what kind of response you get.

General algorithm would be:

1. Separate the 2 different parts

   - Coma-delimitered, equality-valued part
   - XML-formated part
   - This could be done, maybe by finding first index of '<' and splitting the string into 2 in this place
2. Parse the 2 parts with different algorithm. In first case, the parsing shouldn't be a problem. Just split along ',' and '=' and you get key-value pairs. In second case, you should use some XML parsing library to help you. Again, you get bunch of key-value pairs.
3. Put all key-value pairs into a string/string dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract them manually by using String.IndexOf..), and then String.SubString(..) etc

```
var cardType = data.Substring(data.IndexOf("<BatchNum>"), data.IndexOf("</BatchNum>") - data.IndexOf("<BatchNum>"));
```

With some exceptions handling code of course...